# Targetting subsets of subscribers via Fuel SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel

Each night we want to take various segments of our users, and send them an email based on which segment they're in (if any).

The quick and dirty option is to create and delete multiple lists each night.

Is there a more elegant way to approach this?

e.g. I like the idea of using Groups, and toggling some custom "segment membership" fields on users in a single subscriber List, then sending to the groups, but this can't be done via Fuel as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

are you using Subscriber List or Data Extensions? If you are on the list then groups would definitely be the better way of going about it. With data extensions you simply create filters and then send to the segmented DE's.

In both scenarios you can refresh the audiences before triggering sends ensuring that you always send to the most recent subscriber base for the given segmentation rules.

Cheers,
Vlad

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to do this with Fuel as far as I can tell, though.  Am I missing something, or how would I go about using groups programmatically?

Comment: Hey @Mark, can you please confirm what exactly is not possible to do via Fuel? From what I can see you'll just need to create groups via UI, then when making a send simply nominate relevant group as an audience to the send.